# Python in docker – RuntimeError: can't start new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, docker, concurrency

I'm unable to debug one error myself. I'm running python 3.8.12 inside docker image on Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five) and I'm unable to spawn threads from python. It's required for `boto3` transfer to run in parallel and it uses `concurrent.features` to do so.

The simplest example which replicates my issue without any dependencies is ([copied from python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example))

```py
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            pass
```

sadly output of these lines is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <dictcomp>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 188, in submit
    self._adjust_thread_count()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 213, in _adjust_thread_count
    t.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 852, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

That's all I have. Is there place where should I look? I've already checked `ulimit` which says `unlimited`. I'm kind of despair where to look or what to change to debug this issue.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Solution to this problem was to upgrade docker from version 18.06.1-ce to 20.10.7.

**Why?**

> This is because the default seccomp profile of Docker 20.10.9 is not adjusted to support the clone() syscall wrapper of glibc 2.34 adopted in Ubuntu 21.10 and Fedora 35.

Source: [ubuntu:21.10 and fedora:35 do not work on the latest Docker (20.10.9)](https://medium.com/nttlabs/ubuntu-21-10-and-fedora-35-do-not-work-on-docker-20-10-9-1cd439d9921)

Comment: To anyone who saw this in a bitbucket pipeline self hosted runner which run a dind image, this fix applies too. Upgrading to docker:20.10.24-dind did the trick.

Comment: Same issue on gitlab pipelines, 20.10.24 verison fixed my issue. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: This is a great advice. In my case simply downgrading the base image from _bookworm_ to _bullseye_ solved the issue. That is, glibc of Debian 11 must be still compatible with Docker _19.03.13_. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting event after having `20.10.8` docker version

Answer (score 26):

I had this problem when installing Flask in docker. The progress bar caused this problem, so I solved it by `pip install Flask --progress-bar off`

Comment: solution also worked for me when installing Cython

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. Kudos on finding that fix.

Comment: Yes this works when building the docker file, but the error still appears when running the docker file

Comment: Also worked for me, but I used to disable the progress bar globally via settings, as mentioned in risahbhc32 answer: `RUN pip config --user set global.progress_bar off`

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was using

```
FROM python:3.8
```

I changed it to

```
FROM python:3.8-bullseye
```

And it worked for me.

For more info [Build started failing using Python:3.8 Docker image on apt-get update and install with GPG error: bookworm InRelease is not signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76955036/build-started-failing-using-python3-8-docker-image-on-apt-get-update-and-instal)

Answer (score 5):

I also got this problem, and after I added **--privileged** when do docker run, the problem fixed, hope it can help you.

If you use docker-compose,

```
web:
  image: an_image-image:1.0
  container_name: my-container
  privileged: true
```

Answer (score 3):

I was deploying a FastAPI asyncio server container on **Ubuntu 18** with **Docker version 19.03.12** and was getting the following error:

```py
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 935, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

My Environment:

- Docker Image: `python:3.9-slim`
- Python dependencies: `uvicorn==0.24.0.post1`, `gunicorn==21.2.0`, `httpx==0.25.1`

As mentioned by @Yuri Pozniak in the accepted answer's comment that downgrading to Debian bullseye worked.

I just changed the docker image from `python:3.9-slim` to `python:3.9-slim-bullseye` and everything started working fine.

Additionally, I also had to disable pip progress bar in the Dockerfile:

- `RUN pip config --user set global.progress_bar off`

Comment: I only added `RUN pip config --user set global.progress_bar off ` and it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

pip uses thread to show progress bar. Try to disable it

```
RUN pip install --progress-bar off -r requirements.txt
```

Reference : https://forums.docker.com/t/runtimeerror-cant-start-new-thread/138142

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build this Docker container on AWS with CodeBuild and you are using multistage builds, you might need to enable concurrent builds.

Here are some parameters that you might want to look into: DOCKER_BUILDKIT, DOCKER_CLI_AGGREGATE.

Here is an example: [Enabling Docker Buildkit in AWS CodeBuild/CodePipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73439493/enabling-docker-buildkit-in-aws-codebuild-codepipeline)