# Enabling Docker Buildkit in AWS CodeBuild/CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm encountering the following error in the AWS CodePipeline:

```
Step 9/12 : RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache pipenv sync
the --mount option requires BuildKit. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/buildkit/ to learn how to build images with BuildKit enabled
error  : [100%] fail: docker --config /tmp/cdkDockerConfigVtUKNx build --tag cdkasset-c2b7e076bc767541a1f827d091762bd74881ca1fde81050637edab953a2eb411 . exited with error code 1: the --mount option requires BuildKit. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/buildkit/ to learn how to build images with BuildKit enabled
```

Here's the Dockerfile up to the failing command:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Create the virtualenv
RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN pip install pipenv
ENV PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV VENV_LOCATION=/app/.venv/

WORKDIR /app

ADD Pipfile Pipfile.lock /app/
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache pipenv sync
```

Following the link in the error message I come to https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds where it says:

> Easiest way from a fresh install of docker is to set the DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 environment variable when invoking the docker build

However it's not clear if there's any way to do this from within AWS CodePipeline.  I can see some docs on DockerBuildAssetOptions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/DockerBuildAssetOptions.html

but there are no examples of their usage within the cdk examples repo on github:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/search?q=DockerBuildAssetOptions

any suggestions very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for our cdk setup appears to be:

```
getCodeBuildOptions(accountConfig: Account, pipelineConfig: Instance<ApplicationConfig>): pipelines.CodeBuildOptions {
    const defaults = super.getCodeBuildOptions(accountConfig, pipelineConfig);
    return {
        ...defaults,
        buildEnvironment: {
            ...defaults.buildEnvironment,
            environmentVariables: {
                DOCKER_BUILDKIT: {
                    value: '1',
                },
            },
        },
    };
}
```