# Build started failing using Python:3.8 Docker image on apt-get update and install with GPG error: bookworm InRelease is not signed

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, debian, debian-bookworm

My build pipeline has stopped working all of a sudden which was working fine a few weeks ago. I'm using Dockerfile to build my app with `python:3.8` as the base image. It has started failing on the `apt-get update && apt-get install` part. I didn't change anything in the Dockerfile.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8
...
...
...
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev git jq tree
...
...
...
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
```

**What is the cause of this? How to fix it?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Why this happened?**

The Python docker images have been updated recently to use Debian 12 `bookworm` version which was released on 10 June 2023 instead of Debian 10 `buster`.

Sources:

- [GitHub > docker-library/python > Commit > add bookworm, remove buster](https://github.com/docker-library/python/commit/5d908b0477c003712550c84ac4d133367b912f78)
- [Wikipedia > Debian version history > Release table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Release_table)

**What is the root cause?**

> It is Docker with libseccomp so a newer syscall used in Debian Bookworm packages/libs is being blocked. libseccomp lets you configure allowed syscalls for a process. Docker sets a default seccomp profile for all containers such that only certain syscalls are allowed and everything else is blocked (so, newer syscalls that are not yet known to libseccomp or docker are blocked).

Source: [python:3.9 - Failed run apt update from the last version of the image #837](https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/837#issuecomment-1599640563)

**Possible Solutions:**

Either

- Add the following in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN mv -i /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-*.asc  /root/
RUN ln -s /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-* /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
```

Or

- Use any of the `bullseye` image (e.g., `python:3.8-slim-bullseye`).

Or

- Update `libseccomp` and `docker` on the host running the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the docker system is the only solution that worked for me.

The ones listed above are not always applicable, e.g. if you are building not directly from a python:3.8 image, but from some image that derives from it, then you have no control over what is the base debian version.