# Synapse stopped working after dockerfile update

Tags: matrix, matrix-synapse

i am running a matrix-synapse server behind an nginx using docker

i had in my dockerfile a line :

`image: matrixdotorg/synapse:latest` (which was, in hindsight,  dumb...)

and i think was around 1.80-88 ....

the server stopped speaking to my element client on a tablet, so i thought to update the image....

stopped the server, pulled, restarted....
server didn't restart....

i tried to go back to 1.88, no luck, went forward explicitely to 1.95, same error for all versions:

```
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: 2023-11-08 23:00:31,979 - synapse.federation.federation_server - 1387 - INFO - main - Registering federation query handler for 'profile'
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: 2023-11-08 23:00:31,980 - synapse.federation.federation_server - 1367 - INFO - main - Registering federation EDU handler for 'm.presence'
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: 2023-11-08 23:00:31,983 - synapse.federation.federation_server - 1367 - INFO - main - Registering federation EDU handler for 'm.typing'
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: 2023-11-08 23:00:31,984 - synapse.federation.federation_server - 1387 - INFO - main - Registering federation query handler for 'directory'
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: 2023-11-08 23:00:31,984 - twisted - 275 - INFO - main - Redirected stdout/stderr to logs
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: 2023-11-08 23:00:31,984 - synapse.app.homeserver - 173 - INFO - sentinel - Running
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: 2023-11-08 23:00:31,987 - synapse.app.homeserver - 29 - INFO - sentinel - Set file limit to: 1048576
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: 2023-11-08 23:00:31,989 - twisted - 275 - CRITICAL - sentinel - Unhandled Error
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 502, in fireEvent
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     DeferredList(beforeResults).addCallback(self._continueFiring)
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 645, in addCallback
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     return self.addCallbacks(callback, callbackArgs=args, callbackKeywords=kwargs)
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 558, in addCallbacks
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     self._runCallbacks()
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1101, in _runCallbacks
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: --- <exception caught here> ---
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 514, in _continueFiring
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     callable(*args, **kwargs)
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 237, in _start
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     return self.start()
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 247, in start
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     self.threadpool.start()
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 158, in start
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     self.adjustPoolsize()
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 304, in adjustPoolsize
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     self._team.grow(self.min - self.workers)
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/_threads/_team.py", line 117, in grow
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     @self._coordinator.do
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/_threads/_threadworker.py", line 107, in do
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     working.pop(0)()
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/_threads/_team.py", line 120, in createOneWorker
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     worker = self._createWorker()
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/_threads/_pool.py", line 55, in limitedWorkerCreator
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     return ThreadWorker(startThread, Queue())
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/_threads/_threadworker.py", line 49, in __init__
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     startThread(work)
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/twisted/_threads/_pool.py", line 49, in startThread
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     return threadFactory(target=target).start()
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 964, in start
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]:     _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
Nov  9 00:00:31 localhost matrix.nohkumado.eu[1339]: builtins.RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

followed by some more errors of the same type

so something fundamental  seems to be broken, since the load on that machine is otherwise light?

how can i get this working again?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Upgrading docker-ce resolved the issue:

```
sudo apt upgrade docker-ce
```

References here:

- https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/issues/16716
- [Python in docker – RuntimeError: can't start new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087344/python-in-docker-runtimeerror-cant-start-new-thread)