Why 'OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 1 of 2: Operation not permitted' in a container?
Why would
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 1 of 2: Operation not permitted

occur in a FROM ubuntu:22.04 container (when it does not occur in other containers or the host machine?)
Things checked:

ulimit -a | grep max user processes

max user processes              (-u) 31136


cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/pids.max

cat: /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/pids.max: No such file or directory


docker inspect image_name | grep PidsLimit

            "PidsLimit": 0,


docker run ... --env OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=2 ...

No behaviour change


docker run ... --env OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 ...

It runs, but our code needs 2 threads, so errors later


latest numpy version in other container that runs

1.23.5 (but doesn't run in new container, so that's not the culprit)



Will try to generate a minimal example next and share here
EDIT: Still don't know why. However running docker run with --privileged allows the usage of all the threads again

Thanks for the privileged flag. Also, the root cause of this issue is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70093119/1874627

Run with options below may solve it:
docker run --security-opt seccomp:unconfined ...

It works for me.

Add configurations below to /etc/docker/daemon.json may has the same effect. It is more convenient, but may be a minor security issue.
{
  "seccomp-profile": "unconfined"
}

It does not work for me.

Set seccomp-profile to unconfined, which will disable all profiles of secure computing mode. See also: Seccomp security profiles for Docker.
